# Windows 10 Mobile hotspot with static IP

Tags: windows-10, static-ip, hotspot

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure the Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot such that the devices connected are given the same IP address every time. I believe this is done as a Static IP but I don't know how this can be done within Windows.

Comment: In some cases it's possible to define it in the devices themselves.

Comment: IP addresses are handed out by the DHCP server, which on an internet connection is the ISP. If the ISP supports static IPs over their cellular networks then you'll be able to do this. If you try doing this from the client side without appropriate configuration upstream on the provider side, you won't get internet.